# Does Mathematica support connection to mongo Database?

Tags: mongodb, mathematica-8, database

Is it possible to connect Mathematica to a mongo database? or is Mathematica only able to connect to SQL databases?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/graph-databases-nosql-with-mathematica

Comment: Just an FYI: full support for MongoDB is coming in version 11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Language version 11.3 now has support: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MongoLink/guide/MongoLinkOperations.html

You can connect to a MongoDB database via `MongoConnect`. For example, connecting to a database running locally:

```
In[1]:= Needs["MongoLink`"]
client = MongoConnect[];
MongoGetDatabaseNames[client]

Out[2]= {"Test", "admin"}
```

Comment: @chade_: fixed.